# simulate generics with protocol buffer

Tags: c#, generics, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a class that stores and manipulates some entities. Depending on the number of inputs, I may not be able to store entities in memory, so I'm trying to serialize my objects to be written on hard disk using protocol buffers. I'm using C# and [protobuf-csharp-port](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/). I'm aware of [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) as an alternative port; so far I have been working with first option but I'm open for changes if it's required based on my needs.

The class to be serialized in it's simplified form is as follows:

```
class Entity<T> where T: IComparable<T>
{
    int id;
    T metaData;
}
```

So at compile time I have no clues about `metaData`. Googling I noticed that extensions are the right path to follow (as suggested on [google's page](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278483/protocol-buffers-with-extensions)); hence I'm defining the `Entity.proto` file for class `Entity` as following:

```
message Entity
{
    required int32 id = 1 [default = 0];
    extensions 2 to max; 
}
```

and I would like the user to provide his own `.proto` file for `T` without the need to access or re-compile `Entity.proto`. In this regard, my questions are:

1. Do I need to change `Entity.proto` ?
2. What should be the `T.proto` ?
3. How can I access `T` in my C# code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that scheme, any extensions are going to be *child values* (not subclasses) of the non-generic `Entity`. That doesn't sound like generics, but ultimately storage (serialization) is often quite different to implementation (`Entity<T>` etc). If you can manuallyap between them: fine. But it isn't something the library will provide, AFAIK.

For completeness, in protobuf-net terms: it is perfectly fine with `Entity<T>` - it essentially considers each (`Entity<Foo>`, `Entity<Bar>`, etc) to be completely separate messages. Protobuf-net isn't hugely motivated by .proto schemas (although a code-gen tool is provided, for completeness) - it mainly uses runtime metadata.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: protobuf-net supports generics, which then I can compile my library with `Entity<T>` and it's serializer (1). When using the library, along with `T` user will also provide it's serializer (2). Ultimately an instance of `Entity<T>` will be serialized using (1) and (2).

Comment: @hamed most commonly when using protobuf-net, you don't distribute a serializer at all: the library will worry about that when needed. The main times you distribute a serializer is for AOT devices

Comment: maybe too much mixing with OOP, but I'm totally confused. `Entity` doesn't know `T` so it can't serialize it. On the other hand, `T` doesn't know `Entity`'s data structure, so neither it can provide the serialize. Then I wonder how `Entity<Foo>` is serialized ?

Comment: @Hamed because neither `Entity<>` nor `T` is responsible for serialization. The *library* is - and all it sees is the closed generic type `Entity<Foo>`. Frankly, it doesn't even bother to check whether it *is* generic or not - because that simply doesn't matter.

Comment: This explains. My doubts were raised because I was trying to interpret everything in `.proto` scheme with `Entity<T>` proto generated and compiled at library build time and `T` proto generated and connected to it.

Comment: `protobuf-net` seems very easy to use; but one sentence from [getting started page](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted) worries me, sentence is: _The API, however, is very different to Google's, and follows typical .NET patterns (it is broadly comparable, in usage, to XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, etc)_. You mean you are NOT using protocol buffer logics ? or only your interface is very different from it ?

Comment: @Hamed the data format and core concept is identical; only the interface is different: rather than being "the protocol buffers API, written in .NET", it is " a .NET-idiomatic serializer, that happens to be reading/writing protobuf". As such, it is very comparable to other .NET serialization APIs like XmlSerializer, Jil, etc

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to use data serliazed with `protobuf-net` interchangeably in another application that uses the `C++` version of protocol buffer. Hence compatibility is very important, which based on your comment, the serialized data are compatible.

Comment: @Hamed yes, but essentially it is like having lots of different message types: `Entity_Foo`, `Entity_Bar` etc. Just make sure to test everything before settling on an implementation.